# Leer Json en js

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo en php los siguientes arrays

```
$api = array( 
            'PlnDir' => $PlnDir,  
            'Agr' => $Agr, 
            'Emp' => $Emp,
            'Admin' => $Admin
        );

    $datos = array(  
            'menuPV' => $menuPrincipal,  
            'menuSH' => $menuSecundario, 
            'api' => $api
        );

$json = json_encode($datos);
```

En js hago lo siguiente

```
objJson = JSON.parse(json);
```

Si quiero acceder a la primera variable 'menuPV' lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
objJson.menuPV
```

Como podría recorrer el array api que a su vez es un elemento del array datos desde javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es tratarlo como un simple array de javascript:

```
for(var i = 0; i < objJson.api.length; i++ ){
    console.log(objJson.api[i].PlnDir);
}
```

espero haberte entendido bien.